# mongoDB Aggregate-Framework gets slow after adding Index

Tags: performance, mongodb, indexing, aggregation-framework

I've got two duplicated collection with exactly the same information.

Properties mongoDB:
 - Version 2.6
 - VM with 4-Core and 8gb RAM

Properties of the Collection:
 - about 2.200.000 documents 
 - 10gb per collection

To get some information out of it, i use the aggregation framework. It works really well, but it takes to long with about 70 seconds.

```js
db.coll.aggregate( [{
 $group: {
   _id: {
       OWNER: "$OWNER",
       CATEGORY__: "$CATEGORY__"
    },
    VALUE: { $sum: "$VALUE" }
    }
 }])
```

So I implement an index on owner and category....
If I execute the same query, it takes about 150 seconds!

Does someone knows the reason for these contradicting results?

Additional: Only by including $match i can increase the performance. (25 sec)

Comment: You ran these in succession didn't you. You do realize that in your final effort that dumped the index you had to dump all the index pages from memory since they were invalid to your last operation and the data had to be reloaded again from disk. Your testing is not really valid. You need to execute the same queries over and over where you expect the data to be "hot" and loaded for the best chance of the best performance.

Comment: Well thanks for your advice. After implementing the index I ran the first query about 10 times in a row... so the dataload should be "hot".

Comment: My point was you should see consistent results with your first sample on the same query. But really, not only should you get advantage of an index using an initial `$match` but it is also filtering the results going into the further operations. The end result should be faster so I am not sure if there is really a question here. Is there?

Comment: The main problem is not the `$match`...  its the difference beetween the first statement with indexes and without. I know that index doenst work with $group. Never the less, I execute the same query to the first collection with no indexes and the second collection with index... but i thought it would be even better or maybe the same with index. Am I totally wrong? Because it would be negativ, if the index reduces the perfomance of some queries.

Comment: Maybe you should edit your question to include more detail about what you are trying to say. The examples show a `$match` which would use an index reducing the time significantly where as your other operations that cannot use an index run slower. I have really only tried to steer you to making a clear point, or consider the problems in your evaluation.